# How can I track down performance bottlenecks in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I'm want to determine where the lag time is in my application. I'm trying to put together
why my requests are taking much longer than the advertised time. I've included an example from
the log. Between Views and ActiveRecord, the time is only 150ms, but the entire response is
taking 1483ms. That's more than entire second being lost in somewhere that's not
monitored.

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 80.171.62.199 at 2012-05-14 09:51:33 +0000
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"developer_api_key"=>"foo", "user_api_key"=>"bar", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Cors Test"}}
  HTTP Logger Request ID: 4fb0d5a583098e0014000002
Completed 201 Created in 1483ms (Views: 133.2ms | ActiveRecord: 24.0ms)
```

I am using New Relic RPM to monitor application performance, that only shows me:
`ContactsController#index: 426ms`. There is still a bunch for time and code that is
unaccounted for.

What's the best way for me to figure out where the code is spending it's time? Should I invest
in extending New Relic RPM or use something like ruby-prof?

Answer (score 1):

Is this in production? If so, yeah, invest in New Relic or try them out with their free upgrade 'thing' they usually have. i guess you get it for a week, usually. See if they have any deals like that right now.

Also, do you have before_filters, api calls to 3rd party services, Some weird initializers, and is this the first time that POST was called after a server reboot?

You have a developer_api_key which is probably checking something somewhere (locally maybe) or a 3rd party service.

Lots of factors, but it is only a second. Most standard apps would be ok with that on a POST. Unless it's a New Relic clone that takes POSTS and only POSTS, i.e., that is your bread and butter.

Also, do you have an index on the api key? just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The api keys are authentication for the API. The response I posted is from our public API. You need the keys to access. 

I'm going to try the upgraded version for New Relic and see if that gives me some deeper insight into my code.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic is the best tool for this:

http://newrelic.com/

I'm not a fan of advertising products here, but I've used it and it really helps.